# Datagridview with multiple Tableadapters, view different colums for each view

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview with multiple table adapters. every click on the dg exposes a new table on the same control.
How can i show different columns on click?
I've tried to use

```
DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
newCol.CellTemplate = cell;
newCol.HeaderText = "numOfTexts";
newCol.Name = "numOfTexts";
newCol.Visible = true;
dg1.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

but it doesn't display the cell content, only the column name.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

`dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;`

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns%28VS.95%29.aspx)

> true if the columns should be created automatically; otherwise, false. The default is true.

This is exactly what you need to display all columns of the table adapter.

You can hide the unnecessary columns.

Hope I helped...

Comment: You should add link + a quote, especially if you copy/paste. Please review my edit to see what I did.